# Combination of ^< characters in Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'd like to know what does `^<` character combination means in my case. I already know that `^<` helps to interpret `<` as an ordinary character. But what does it mean here:
`for /F %%i in ('^< !FILE! find /C /V ""') do set count=%%i`

I suppose this code counts lines in a particular file but I'm not sure about these characters.

Thanks, I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /F %%i in ('^< !FILE! find /C /V ""') do set count=%%i
```

you are right, the `for` loop populates the variable `%count%` with the number of lines in a file.

The "usual" usage of `find` is `find /c /v "" file.txt` (try it and note the output - not a good output to get the number only).
Therefore `find` gets its input from STDIN: `<file.txt find /c /v ""` (again, try it and note the output - much better for capturing).
The `<` has to be escaped (with a `^`) to not ruin the syntax of the `for` loop.

The part in parentheses runs in a separate instance of `cmd` and you need the `<` in that instance, not in the original instance. Escaping forces the `<` to be treated "as ordinary character" in the original instance. The escape char is removed with the first parsing, sending the plain (unescaped) `<` to the second instance, where it does what it should do. - redirecting the contents of the file to STDIN.

You could also do the same thing by using doublequotes instead of the caret escape character (Thank you @Compo for the suggestion):

```
for /F %%i in ('"< !FILE! find /C /V """') do set count=%%i
```

Strings in quotes are parsed less strictly. [In case you are interested in a more in-depth explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) - be warned - it's hard stuff...